# How is this SQL query and join done in dplyr?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

I'm trying to learn a bit of R, and can't figure out how to join 2 tables with dplyr. If I did this strictly in SQL, I would use:

```
select a1.[some column], a2.[other column], a3.[last column]
from vwTable1 a1
join vwTable2 a2
    on a2.myKey = a1.mykey
join vwTable3 a3
    on a3.otherKey = a1.otherKey
where a2.myItem = '12345'
    and a1.myDate between '1/1/2021' and '3/31/2021'
```

In R, I can connect to the SQL database:

```
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
    Driver = "SQL Server",
    Server = "myServer",
    Database = "myDatabase",
    Port = "1234",
    Trusted_Connection = "Yes")
```

I'm just not sure if I need to establish references first, like:

```
a1 <- tbl(con, "vwTable1")
a2 <- tbl(con, "vwTable2") 
a3 <- tbl(con, "vwTable3")
```

...and then join the 2 references?

The goal is to put the query results into a data frame (if that's the best way to do it) that will be copied to a SQL table on another server.

I did try the following, but R Console just sat there at a + waiting for me to do something else:

```
a4 <- tbl(con, sql("SELECT a1.[some column], a2.[other column], a2.[last column]
    FROM vwTable1 a1
    JOIN vwTable2 a2 on a2.myKey = a1.myKey
    JOIN vwTable3 a3 on a3.otherKey = a1.otherKey
    WHERE a2.myItem = '12345'
        AND a1.myDate BETWEEN '1/1/2021' AND '3/31/2021'))
```

EDIT:

This was the solution:

```
results <- tbl(con, "vwTable1") %>% filter(myDate >= "2021-01-01" & myDate <= "2021-03-31") %>%
inner_join(tbl(con, "vwTable2") %>% filter(myItem == '12345'), by = "myKey") %>%
inner_join(tbl(con, "vwTable3"), by = "otherKey")
```

Comment: Have you checked [dbplyr](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/) by the tidyverse developers ? It has syntax similar to `dplyr` for joining tables (like left join, right join etc.) that would fulfil your needs I believe.

Comment: It looks like your last query is missing closing `"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dplyr syntax would be something like

```
tbl(con, "vwTable1") %>%
  filter(myDate >= "2021-01-01" & myDate <= "2021-01-02") %>%  # edit
  inner_join(tbl(con, "vwTable2") %>%
            filter(myItem == '12345'), 
            by = "myKey") %>%
  inner_join(tbl(con, "vwTable3"), by = "otherKey")

  # Edit - I think the default is inner_join, not left_join as I had originally
```

Comment: Looking at the sql code, the filtering is the last step to be done. ie you first join then you filter. But in your solution, you filter then join

Comment: I tried this and R Console sits there at a + sign. I'm thinking a ) is missing, but not sure where it would go.

Comment: I was able to get this to work with the following:

`results <- tbl(con, "vwTable1") %>% filter(myDate >= "2021-01-01" & myDate <= "2021-01-02") %>%
    inner_join(tbl(con, "vwTable2") %>% filter(myItem == '12345'), by = "myKey") %>%
    inner_join(tbl(con, "vwTable3"), by = "otherKey")`

Comment: Great, updated answer with your filter syntax.